# Why is there no 2* in the space complexity recurrence S(n) = 2*S(n/2)?

Tags: python, space-complexity

```
from typing import List

def recfunc(xs: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    if len(xs) < 2:
        return xs
    a = list()
    b = list()
    for x in range(len(xs)):
        if x < len(xs) // 2:
            a.insert(0, x)
        else:
            b.insert(0, x)
    return recfunc(a) + recfunc(b)
```

The space complexity for this function is `S(n) = S(n/2) + c1*n + c2` for `n>=2` where `S` stands for the space and `c1,c2` are some constants.

Why isn't it `S(n) = S(n/2)*2 + c1*n + c2`?

Comment: Where did this formula come from?

Comment: What is `S`? And `c1` and `c2`?

Comment: I thought folks measured these things with big-O notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your recursive relation, `S(n)` represents the maximum space occupied by a function call to `recfunc` where `n := len(xs)`.

Consider the line of code:

```
return recfunc(a) + recfunc(b)
```

We could have rewritten this as:

```
a_result = recfunc(a)
b_result = recfunc(b)
return a_result + b_result
```

...without changing the space requirements.

At any given time, we only need the space for at most `S(max(len(a), len(b)))`, which is to say, at most `S(n / 2)`. Thus:

```
S(n) = S(n / 2) + ...
```

On the other hand, if you were measuring time complexity with a recursive relation on `T(n)`, then both of the function calls above would have occurred at some point. So we would say:

```
T(n) = 2 * T(n / 2) + ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `recfunc(b)` gets executed **after** `recfunc(a)`, so the same space that was used for `recfunc(a)` can be reused for `recfunc(b)`. It doesn't add up like time does.